# Serializing a class with member that is vector<unique_ptr<string>> with boost::serialization

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

There is a similarly [sounding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038329/), but it is totally different because it relates to a vector of unique_ptr of the class that is serialized.
I would like to have a way to serialize member that is a vector.

[What I have tried and does not work:](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Lt6iDCbi8tZzoHol)

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/forward_list.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
using namespace boost::archive;
class Person {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> data_;
    public:
    Person(){
        data_.emplace_back(nullptr);
        data_.emplace_back(new std::string("Bjarne!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"));
    }
    private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive &ar,const unsigned int)
{
  ar & data_;
}
    public:
    const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>& data() const{
        return data_;
    }

};

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    Person p;
    text_oarchive oa{ss};
    oa << p;
    text_iarchive ia{ss};
    Person read;
    ia >> read;
    for (const auto& ptr : read.data()) {
        std::cout << *ptr; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Vector of pointers to strings doesn't appear meaningfull. Why not just have a vector of strings? Why would you *need* the null-pointers?

Comment: It is an example, It could be a pointer to move only UDT

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is move-only as well, so that wouldn't be the argument... Still accepted, though, as you'd need pointers for *polymorphic* types (well, pointer vs. value issue, the null-pointers are another matter!).

Comment: you are right, better example would be a pointer to a type that does not have efficient move, like large std::array or some antique 3rd party code class.

Comment: Best example a polymorphic type, as you *cannot* do any differently than storing pointers, as you'd suffer from object slicing otherwise ;)

Comment: Seems to have to do with using std::string a wrapper type allow compilation: https://godbolt.org/z/bwYI0L Even a simple example with unique_ptr to string does not work.

Comment: In certain cases you know your data better than a 3rd party library, why not just write your own serializer? You'd write a serialize function for the underlying UDT and one for the class `Person` is standing in for.

Comment: @Casey if you are replacing existing serialization with boost serialize this means rewriting large parts of the serialization code, and existing one already works... so it is not going to happen. :)

Answer (score 1):

As @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts comments, steer clear of using `std::unique_ptr`s for sentinel no-values when you want to serialize, use [`boost::optional`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) instead to [serialize](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/serialization/optional.hpp).